# Ways to assign each of the integers $1$ to $n$ to $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_n$ such that $|a_k − k| ≤ 1$ for $k = 1, 2, . . . , n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Determine the number of ways to assign each of the integers $1$ to $n$ to $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_n$ such that
$|a_k − k| ≤ 1$ for $k = 1, 2, . . . , n$. Your answer should be a closed-form expression.

---

I have no idea how to approach these problems, so can I have some help?

Thanks

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Are you allowed to repeat? (ie can $a_1 = a_2$?)

Comment: You are not allowed to repeat. $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ is a permutation of $(1,2,\cdots,n)$

Comment: Consider the case of $a_x = x$ first. How many possible ways are there to select $k$? The answer below tells you that if you need some help. Once you have that figured out, then factor in how many possible permutations are there for the $a_x$'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_{n}$ be the number of ways. Now we are going to find recurrence relation on $a_{n}$. By assumption, the only possible $k$ for $a_{k} = n$ is $k = n-1$ or $k =n$. If $k=n$, then $a_{1}, \dots, a_{n-1}$ forms a permutation of $1, 2, \dots, n-1$, and there are $x_{n-1}$ ways of permutations. If $k = n-1$, i.e if $a_{n-1} = n$, then we should have $a_{n} = n-1$, since the only possible values for $a_{n}$ are $n-1$ or $n$. Then for the remaining $a_{1}, \dots, a_{n-2}$, there are $x_{n-2}$ such permutations. This proves $x_{n} = x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$, and the initial conditions $x_{1} = 1, x_{2} = 2$ would give a [familiar sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) as an answer.